# SP to compare the columns and data types of two tables and to alter the target table as per the source table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm basically new to SQL and I have a request to create a Stored Procedure to compare the columns of two tables(a source table and a target table).

So first of all in the two tables that are compared(the source table and the target table) if there are no common columns then I need to call a CREATE TABLE procedure to create the source table in the target database or the target schema. I also need help to make the CREATE TABLE procedure.

In the next case scenario if there are matching columns in the two tables them we need to compare the columns.So if in the source table there are like maybe two or three extra columns(even more)compared to the target table then I need to alter the target table so as to add these two or three columns and I also need to alter the data types of the target table (for these added columns) as per the source table. Similarly, if in the target table there are two or three extra columns (or more) as compared to the source table then I need to drop these columns from the target table. So I also need help to call an ALTER TABLE procedure in these cases.

Could anyone help me with the stored procedure?

Comment: I just checked if the columns exist in the target table and then altered the target table if the column is not present in the target table,though i don't know how to create a loop to check all the columns from the source table and I also don't know how to check the data types of the columns and alter likewise.I also have doubt in Creating a new table if there are many  columns to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not claiming this is perfect, and my naming conventions are terrible, but I bashed this out so wanted to share it with you as I hope it gets you started:

```
DECLARE @strTargetTable     NVARCHAR(20)    ,
        @strSourceTable     NVARCHAR(20)    ,
        @intCommonColumns   INT;

SELECT  @strTargetTable = 'Test_Table';
SELECT  @strSourceTable = 'Test1';


SELECT  @intCommonColumns = COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT  TD3.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TD3
    WHERE   TD3.TABLE_NAME  = @strTargetTable
    AND     EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  TD.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   AS TD
    WHERE   TD.TABLE_NAME   = @strSourceTable
    AND     TD3.COLUMN_NAME = TD.COLUMN_NAME
    )
) AS A

/*No common columns*/
IF(@intCommonColumns = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Create table here';
    END

/*Common Columns*/
IF(@intCommonColumns > 0)
    BEGIN 
        /*There are matching columns so figure out what to do with them*/

        /*Create table to hold the columns that need creating*/
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpCreateFirstColumns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpCreateFirstColumns
        CREATE TABLE #tmpCreateFirstColumns
        (
            ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1)       ,
            T_COL_NAME  NVARCHAR(20)            ,
            T_DATA_TYPE NVARCHAR(20)
        )
        INSERT INTO #tmpCreateFirstColumns
        (
            T_COL_NAME  ,
            T_DATA_TYPE
        )
        /*Get columns from the Source table that don't exist in the target*/
        SELECT  TD3.COLUMN_NAME ,
                TD3.DATA_TYPE + CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS NVARCHAR(3))+')' END   
        FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TD3
        WHERE   TD3.TABLE_NAME  = @strSourceTable
        AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  TD.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   AS TD
        WHERE   TD.TABLE_NAME   = @strTargetTable
        AND     TD3.COLUMN_NAME = TD.COLUMN_NAME
        )

        DECLARE @intMinID   INT ,
                @intMaxID   INT ,
                @strSQL     NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SELECT  @intMinID = MIN(TC.ID)  ,
                @intMaxID = MAX(TC.ID)
        FROM    #tmpCreateFirstColumns  AS TC

        WHILE(@intMinID <= @intMaxID)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @strCol NVARCHAR(20)    ,
                        @strData1   NVARCHAR(MAX)   ;

                SELECT  @strCol         =   TC.T_COL_NAME   ,
                        @strData1       =   TC.T_DATA_TYPE
                FROM    #tmpCreateFirstColumns      AS TC
                WHERE   TC.ID = @intMinID;

                SELECT  @strSQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+@strTargetTable+' ADD '+'['+@strCol+']'+' '+@strData1;
                PRINT 'ALTER TABLE '+@strTargetTable+' ADD '+'['+@strCol+']'+' '+@strData1;
                EXEC    sp_executesql @strSQL

                SELECT @intMinID = @intMinID + 1;
            END

        /*Create table to hold the columns that need creating*/
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpCreateColumns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpCreateColumns
        CREATE TABLE #tmpCreateColumns
        (
            ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1)       ,
            T_COL_NAME  NVARCHAR(20)            ,
            T_DATA_TYPE NVARCHAR(20)
        )
        INSERT INTO #tmpCreateColumns
        (
            T_COL_NAME  ,
            T_DATA_TYPE
        )
        /*Get columns from the Source table that don't exist in the target*/
        SELECT  TD3.COLUMN_NAME ,
                TD3.DATA_TYPE + CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS NVARCHAR(3))+')' END   
        FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TD3
        WHERE   TD3.TABLE_NAME  = @strTargetTable
        AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  TD.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM    Test_Database3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   AS TD
        WHERE   TD.TABLE_NAME   = @strSourceTable
        AND     TD3.COLUMN_NAME = TD.COLUMN_NAME
        )

        SELECT  @intMinID = MIN(TCC.ID) ,
                @intMaxID = MAX(TCC.ID)
        FROM    #tmpCreateColumns       AS TCC

        WHILE(@intMinID <= @intMaxID)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @strCol2    NVARCHAR(20)    ,
                        @strData    NVARCHAR(MAX)   ;

                SELECT  @strCol2        =   TCC.T_COL_NAME  ,
                        @strData    =   TCC.T_DATA_TYPE
                FROM    #tmpCreateColumns       AS TCC
                WHERE   TCC.ID = @intMinID;

                SELECT  @strSQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+@strSourceTable+' ADD '+'['+@strCol2+']'+' '+@strData;
                PRINT 'ALTER TABLE '+@strSourceTable+' ADD '+'['+@strCol2+']'+' '+@strData;
                EXEC    sp_executesql @strSQL

                SELECT @intMinID = @intMinID + 1;
            END
        END
```

Comment: Could you please also explain the step to do 'create table' if there are no common columns after the initial checking considering if there are a lot of columns?

Comment: Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp that with the code above should give you enough to create it.

Comment: In the above given program does it check only one column(if there are a lot of extra columns that need to be added in the target table) and alter the target table to add that one additional column(that does not exist in the target table) or does it check all the columns of the source table and target table and does it alter the target table to add all the extra columns in the source table?

Comment: okay so I tried it out and all the columns that are not present in the target table are being created by alter statement.But then along with these steps itself is there any way to insert the data in those extra columns in the source table into the newly created  columns in the target table?(Because all the data in the newly created columns in the target table shows null)

Comment: Please ignore the above two questions.Could you please explain on how like if in case the source table has two columns and the target table has maybe four columns.(2 of those 4 columns are similar to those of the source table).In this case I need to drop the two additional columns of the target table.How is this executed along with the above program?

Comment: In the last part of the  above program it gives the code to compare the target table and the source table and alter the source table if there are additional columns in the target table right?Instead could you please explain how to drop extra columns from the target table if they are not  present in the source table?(please check my previous question)    --Thank you--

Comment: Okay.So i understood how to drop columns from the target table if they are not present in the source table.Could you please tell me how to like compare the data types of all the columns(including columns which have the same name and different data types)and alter the data types of the columns in the target table which have the same name as in the source table but may have different data types?(so that all columns in the target table would be become exactly like the source table in terms of the column names and also the data types)

Comment: Use the column name to join and compare the data types. You can then alter as needed, however, if there is already data in the columns, you may have issues changing the data type. If that is the case, you may need to create  a 'staging' column to put the data, convert the column, then move it back, then drop it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?I dont know how to compare the data types after joining them.And also could you please explain how to create a 'staging' column and do those processes?

Comment: I don't know what the rules are here, but you are going off topic on your question, so you may be better placed to ask a new one. That said, I have two tables, Test1 and Test_Table, the following SQL will find the columns in the two tables that have the same name, but different data types: SELECT  T1.COLUMN_NAME ,
   T1.DATA_TYPE ,
   TT.COLUMN_NAME ,
   TT.DATA_TYPE
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS T1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS TT ON TT.COLUMN_NAME = T1.COLUMN_NAME AND TT.TABLE_NAME = 'Test_Table'
WHERE  T1.TABLE_NAME = 'Test1'
AND   T1.DATA_TYPE <> TT.DATA_TYPE

Comment: 'Staging' column, simply create a column as the needed data type, cast the data from one column to the staging column so you can get rid of the data in it. Then alter the column to the required data type, then move the data from the staging column into the column you have altered the data type on, then drop the staging column. If I may say, this requirement is quite odd, may I ask what the issue is you are facing?

Comment: The task is to compare two tables from maybe different schema/db.If the sourcetable doesn't exist in the target  schema/db,then i need to create that table there.If the table exists then we need to compare the columns of the source table and the target table and alter the target table so that the columns of the source and target table are all the same.Also I need to compare and alter the data types of the columns of target table if there is a mismatch with the data types of the columns of the source table(columns with same names).I have to create a stored procedure to perform all these tasks.

Comment: I understand that is the task, my question was more, why are you doing this? What is its practical purpose? Or is this a task for a school question?

Comment: Oh.I'm doing an internship in the Data Analytics branch of EY right now.So this was the task I was asked to perform.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the data type of a column if there is data already present in the column?How do we move the data in one column fully into another column?

Comment: It depends if it can be implicitly converted other wise you will have to explicitly convert it. Take a read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine You can update a whole column just using the UPDATE clause, so set one column to equal the other.

Comment: Okay.So for implicit conversions we could directly use the alter column syntax right?

Comment: Yes - And where it cannot be converted you will get a conversion failed error so you would have to address your data.

Comment: For implical conversions the same program method can be used right which you had given above for alter table?

Comment: And for the one's where we cannot implically convert we would need to use Casting or Converting right?

Comment: No necessarily, it depends on what you are doing. You couldn't conver a string of '444A' to an INT, but you could '444' etc. If you need specific help, you're best asking a new question.

Comment: Yeah when explicit conversions are possible then we use casting or 'convert' right?For implicit conversions can the same program method be used right which you had given above for alter table?

Comment: I'd suggest getting some test data and trying it. It should work, so long as you can convert it or SQL can. SQL Express is free...

Comment: In the SP,while executing this part-  { select * into #tmp_info
from [@db2name].[@schema2name].[@tablename]  }it returns an error saying invalid object name  '@db2name.@schema2name.@tablename'. (@db2name,@schema2name,@tablename are passed as parameters in the SP).Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: You can't pass in database names, schema and table names as variables when selecting directly from them. If you want to do that, you would need to build it as a string and use sp_executesql to execute it

Comment: Can you please tell me how to build  this { select * into #tmp_info from [@db2name].[@schema2name].[@tablename] } into a string and use that sp_executesql?

Comment: Google is your friend.....https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks will check it out. :)

Comment: {set @sqlcommand ='select * 
into' +#tmp_info+'
from '+'['+@db2name+']'+'.'+'['+@schema2name+']'+'.'+'['+@tablename+']';
execute sp_executesql @sqlcommand}   This is showing an error invalid column name '#temp_info'.Can you please tell me the problem?

Comment: Why is #tmp_info not just part of the string?

Comment: {set @sqlcommand ='select * 
into #tmp_info 
from'+'['+@db2name+']'+'.'+'['+@schema2name+']'+'.'+'['+@tablename;
execute sp_executesql @sqlcommand;
declare @c int = (select count(*) from #tmp_info)}                            Okay so now it gives error as Invalid object name '#tmp_info'.

Comment: Have to see your full code to answer properly as I am presuming you have created that temp table and it is available within the transaction? You're best asking another question, this has turned into a one to one.

Comment: Could you maybe give me your email id?I'll send you the code.(almost most of it is based on the code that you gave above).But i need to pass databases,schemas and tables too.

Comment: if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmp_info') is not null
drop table #tmp_info
declare @ sqlcommand nvarchar(1000);
select @ sqlcommand = 'select * into' ;
select @ sqlcommand = @ sqlcommand + ' #tmp_info from ' + @db2name+'.'+@schema2name+'.'+@tablename;
execute sp_executesql @sqlcommand;
declare @c int = (select count(*) from  #tmp_info);

Comment: This is how I tried it and it shows invalid object name #tmp_info.Could you please help?

Comment: Hey please check the given link.I've put the code into this sheet.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rLA6UnrYB0hN58VDeD4L_O9Lh6_tGB2jeO4_r8p6Ebs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you google it, it is because sp_executesql has its own session, so the temp table only exists in that session. Include all you need to be executed by it: select @ sqlcommand = 'SELECT * INTO #tmp_info FROM ' + @ db2name+'.'+@ schema2name+'.'+@ tablename + ' SELECT * FROM #tmp_info'; 

PRINT @ sqlcommand

exec sp_executesql @ sqlcommand;

Comment: A better way, in my opinion, is to create the temp table first, then use the dynamic sql to insert into it. Then the session differences doesn't cause you any issues.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check if a table exists in a database?What i need to check is like,first of all i need to check if a table exists in the target database.If it doesn't exist,i need to directly create such a table in the target db.If it exists then the steps above and all(comparison as mentioned in the actual qn).Can you please tell me so how to check like by giving conditions,so that if the table exists,then i need to execute a set of statements and if it doesn't exist then another set of statements.

Comment: Please check this doc. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rLA6UnrYB0hN58VDeD4L_O9Lh6_tGB2jeO4_r8p6Ebs/edit     I need some way to change the initial checking part for the table..Because here when there is no table of that name in the target db then it shows error as invalid object name.

Comment: Google IF EXISTS and IF NOT EXISTS it is all there.

Comment: I tried doing it dynamically like this.  {declare @fulltable nvarchar(50);

SET @fulltable=@db2name+'.'+@schema2name+'.'+@tablename

IF OBJECT_ID(@fulltable) is NOT NULL

BEGIN

Comment: Thanks for all the help. :) The entire SP is working.